# How do you get nano/pico running on OpenSolaris?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

We're setting up an OpenSolaris server on Amazon's EC2 service. However, vi/vim doesn't work properly, and pkg doesn't have nano/pico.

Is there any other text-editor maybe?

Comment: Not to dodge the question, but what about vi isn't working?

Comment: erickson: picocontainer is the wrong tag. pico was the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may just need to set an appropriate termtype to get vi working.  Look into the "TERM" environment variable options, perhaps one of those will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try copying the nano binaries (or compiling the source), to your user account and running it from there. It worked for me in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://www.sunfreeware.com/?

Answer (score 0):

SUN is working on the SUNWgnu-nano package to include this in the next release. In the meantime, you can compile the nano sources yourself. It worked for me. To compile, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you install SUNWgcc package so that gcc is installed.
2. Download the source package from the debian distribution.
   http://packages.debian.org/source/stable/nano
3. Unzip the package with 'gunzip xxxx.tar.gz' where xxxx.tar.gz is the source package you downloaded.
4. Untar the package with 'tar -xf xxxx' where xxxx is the unzipped source package.
5. Go to the source folder. Do a './configure' to create the make file for your system.
6. Type 'make' to create the binary
7. The 'nano' binary should be located in the src subfolder. Copy this to '/usr/bin'. And create a soft link for 'pico' to it i.e. 'ln -s /usr/bin/nano pico'

Test it out!

Answer (score 0):

1) Open the Package Manager (System > Administration > Package Manager)
2) Open the Repository settings (Settings > Manage Repositories)
3) Add the Blastwave repository (Name: blastwave, URL: http://blastwave.network.com:10000 )
4) Select the repository in the upper right corner
5) Search for the package 'IPSnano'
6) Select the pacakge
7) Press 'Install/Update'

8) Modify your path to include /opt/csw/bin
(For example $ vi ~/.profile   and then add the line above to your path)
9) Logout and in again to reflect the changes

Check whether the correct version of nano is used:
$ which nano

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both Nano and Pico are available as auto-generated packages in the "pending" repository here: http://pkg.opensolaris.org/pending/en/index.shtml.  I think they are waiting for someone to follow the verification steps and vouch that they work.  Then they can be moved to the contrib repository.  You can read more here: http://opensolaris.org/os/community/sw-porters/.